# How to call Watson APIs with proxy set

Tags: node.js, proxy, ibm-watson

I'm trying to call some API, and currently my server make request for firewall, and I need to set proxy to pass, because the with proxy works perfectly and for security reason's the Company can't release the firewall for me.

Summary: How to call this API setting my proxy server with code in my server to all requests using proxy?

I try use express-http-proxy and http-proxy and I try:

```
require('dotenv').config({silent: true});

var httpProxy = require('http-proxy');

var server = require('./app', httpProxy.createServer(function (req, res, proxy) {
  var buffer = httpProxy.buffer(req);

  proxy.proxyRequest(req, res, {
    host: 'pxdproxy.com',
    port: 8080,
    buffer: buffer
  });
});


var port = process.env.PORT || process.env.VCAP_APP_PORT || 443;

server.listen(port, function() {
  // eslint-disable-next-line
  console.log('Server running on port: %d', port);
});
```

and my call for API:

```
var conversation = watson.conversation({
    url: 'https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/conversation/api',
    username: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    password: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    version_date: '2017-12-03',
    version: 'v1',  
});
```

I need to call the Conversation API with proxy set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SDK you are using to call the Watson API from Node.JS uses the [`request`](https://github.com/request/request) library.

In order to use a proxy to call the services, you just need to define an environment variable called `HTTPS_PROXY`.

Based on your example you will use:

```
HTTPS_PROXY=pxdproxy.com:8080
```

More information [here](https://github.com/request/request#controlling-proxy-behaviour-using-environment-variables).